# Keras save best model once it reaches training

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using Keras' callback ModelCheckpoint to save the weights for the best model.

However, sometimes the best validation accuracy (which is the metric I monitor) is high at the beginning of the training because there is quite a lot of noise in my model. But I do not wish to save this model because it hasn't had time to learn yet.

I'd like to get the best model FROM a certain epoch, that ideally I'd get by checking that the training accuracy is > 95%, so I know that I am getting the best model after it has learnt the features in the training dataset.

Is there a way to to this with Keras' callbacks or otherwise?

Comment: you can write a custom callback.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking of that. Do you know how I can access the train accuracy from this custom callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a custom callback function, which gets triggered after every epoch.

The function on_epoch_end in your custom callback function is triggered, with "logs" as one of its parameter.

As per the document, the parameters are

> epoch: integer, index of epoch.
>
> logs: dict, metric results for this training epoch, and for the
>   validation epoch if validation is performed. Validation result keys
>   are prefixed with `val_`.

so you can access the accuracy by logs["accuracy"] inside the on_epoch_end method in you custom call back class.

To save the model weights, refer to this line inside ModelCheckpoint callback method,it a simple function call.

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/callbacks/callbacks.py#L727

So basically your code will look something like this

```
class MyCallback(Callback):
    def __init__():
        #TODO
        #INITIALIZE ALL U NEED, lets say the accuracy threshold, filepath to save the model etc.. 
    def on_epoch_end(self,epoch,logs=None):
        if(logs["accuracy"]>0.95):
            #TODO SAVE MODEL
            self.model.save_weights(filepath)
```

Comment: Thanks. This looks good but I would need to also add the logic to only save the best model, so I was thinking of maybe overwriting the existing ModelCheckpoint callback to add my one condition on the train accuracy, does it make sense?

Comment: Yes. You can look at the implementation of the exiting code and copy it and edit it in your callback

Comment: Yes! I endep up doing this exactly. Thanks again, I will mark your answer as correct